# Couchbase Indexing

Tags: indexing, couchbase

If I create an atom increment to use as an index, eg "post::1", "post::2" etc, it will sort fine up until it reaches the next key length because of the unicode collation.

Is there a better practice for indexing for later searching with views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use padding?

```
key = sprintf("post::%08d", counter)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Couchbase keys are all strings so 12 sorts before 2. So I'm wondering if with an atom counter as a key index do I need to pad it with 0s. Even 0000000012 will sort before 000000002

Comment: It correct but my example doesn't just add 8 zeroes. For 2 it pad 7 zeroes, for 12 only 6.